# What does intensity mean intensity exactly?

Tags: pcl, ros-lunar, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am getting a from a rosbag a point cloud which as been register with a velodyne. I'm visualizing it with a PointCloud2 display type.

I have some artifacts on the result so I'm trying to understand exactly what is appending, but i don't understand what Intensity mean in the "Channel Name" field or in the "Color Transformer" field.

Does someone can help me understand what the intensity represent ? Is it the number of point at the same place ?

I looked in the documentation i founded but whiteout any success...
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud2
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloudShared#channels

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296259/what-does-intensity-mean-intensity-exactly-?/) by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding LiDAR data intensity refers to the energy of the reflected laser pulse. This is a secondary measurement on most modern LiDAR sensors alongside the primary time measurement used to determine depth.

The exact units of these measurements vary from one manufacturer to another but essentially represent the infrared reflectance of the surface at that point, often normalised for depth.

In RVIZ when you select 'intensity' you're telling RVIZ to color the point cloud displayed with the intensity values of each point. Using this coloring it is usually possible to make out the patterns of different materials or paints on flat surfaces for example.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on 2018-07-06**:
Thanks a lot for your answer! That's exactly what I was asking for!

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2022-07-25**:
Related https://answers.ros.org/question/11020/what-does-the-intensity-channel-of-a-point-cloud-refer-to/